# Rails 4 cannot access environment variable but it is available in shell and IRB

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, environment-variables, puma

As per the 12 factor app I'm storing several external API passwords in environment variables. This works great in development but I've hit a snag on my production server. The environment variable is accessed in a method in my `ApplicationController` so that is available to all models.

Running Rails 4.0.2 using Puma 2.8.2 under Ubuntu 14.04. Ruby 2.1.2. Deploying with Capistrano 3.

For sake of discussion I'll call the environment variable PASSWORD and the value 'somepassword'.

**In development**:
I use `dotenv` to load these passwords from `.env` (not checked in source control of course).

- From the CLI I can run `echo $PASSWORD` and I get "somepassword" back
- From IRB I can run ENV['PASSWORD'] and I get "somepassword" back
- Rails can successfully read ENV['PASSWORD']

**In production**:
I use a `chef` recipe to access an encrypted data bag plus the `magic_shell` cookbook to load the password securely as an environment variable.

- From the CLI I can run `echo $PASSWORD` and I get "somepassword" back
- From IRB I can run ENV['PASSWORD'] and I get "somepassword" back
- *Rails fails to read ENV['PASSWORD']*

Note that in the production environment I'm logged in as the same user that starts the `puma` daemon and I'm able to read the variable fine from the CLI and IRB.

**Any ideas** why Rails is unable to access the variable when I'm able to manually access it from the CLI?

I could go a `config/passwords.yml` route (for example) that I encrypt and distribute with `chef` but the environment variable setup should work too.

Comment: I don't know much about chef or 12 factor or such... but where do you set the environment variable? Because if you do it in a shell, this won't get necessarily loaded by the webserver process (or whatever takes care of running your app)

Comment: I'm using the `magic_shell` cookbook (https://github.com/customink-webops/magic_shell). Perhaps this is just the wrong tool for the job and I need to edit /etc/environment directly or go the YML route.

Comment: In the projects I am working, there are files like `/config/initializers/password.rb` setting the passwords, and in the git repo we have only `/config/initializers/password.rb_example`templates. Maybe this helps, although it seems not to be very clean :)

Comment: I tried directly appending `/etc/environment` with ENV variable, but Rails was still unable to access the var. I ended up doing as I mentioned at the end of my questino and as @contradictioned mentioned above: creating a passwords.yml file and pulling it into Rails that way. I would still love to know why Rails mysteriously cannot access my custom ENV variables in production but can access just fine in development.